# search programatically

Tags: 2010, search

I have

list1
 columna
 columnb

list2
 columnc
 columnd

list3
 columne
 columnf

i want to create a search code that will search ONLY on those lists and ONLY on some columns of the lists.
It will be an application page or webpart page.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow below steps:

1) Create a new scope and include all the 3 lists by adding rules : 
Folder = http://siteurl/lists/list1,Folder = http://siteurl/lists/list2,Folder = http://siteurl/lists/list3

2) Do a full crawl

3) Create Managed properties for the columns you want to search.Crawl Again.

4) Now, if you want to search in columnb ( for which you created 'ColumnB' as Managed Property), Go to the search center and enter below keyword query :

```
ColumnB:"MyKeywordtoSearch" Scope:"YourScopeName"
```

Comment: For more information on Keyword query,Check this out : http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2011/10/28/sharepoint-keywordquery/

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to create one Managed property mapping all the crawled properties columna-columnf.
The your Keyword search would be:

> site:urlOfList1 site:urlOfList2 site:urlOfList3 managedProp:searchterm