# Using search web-part to search a custom list's topic questions

Tags: web-part, search

How can I use the search web part to look through a custom list and display the relevant topics from that list to the user?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a scope for that list and add Managed Property for the columns you want to search.

Check the similar  question here : [search programatically](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32695/search-programatically/32711#32711)

Comment: how is it that i can create a new scope?

Comment: Check here :http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792872.aspx

Comment: Are lists automatically searchable with a webpart using site:urlofsite appended to the query put in...example, in a list i created i have setup a Q and A format and I have a site page with a search box webpart on it with the appended query string with the site being the list but i still get no results, is there something else i can do?